# No matching member function call to 'push_back', vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a `Container` class that is meant to store a vector of shared pointers. Whenever an item is appended to the `Container`, I want it to assume ownership of that item. In other words, when the `Container` is deconstructed, all of the elements inside it should also be deconstructed.

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vec_;


public:
    void append(std::shared_ptr<T> item)
    {
        vec_.push_back(std::move(item));
    }

    void printElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_.size(); i++) { std::cout << vec_[i] << std::endl; }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::unique_ptr<Container<std::string>> c = std::make_unique<Container<std::string>>();
    c->append(std::make_shared<std::string>("hello"));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I get the following error on `vec_.push_back(std::move(item))`.

`No matching member function for call to 'push_back'`

I'm not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: Why not use a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Your vec_ is const. Seems to me that would forcefully remove or disable any method, such as push_back, which tries to modify the const vector.

Comment: @GabrielStaples thanks, removing `const` did the trick. I thought `const` only protected against reassignment of `vector_` but allowed for it to be mutated?

Comment: @cigien this was a toy example to debug another class which requires `shared_ptr`

Comment: Since that's it, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: "I thought const only protected against reassignment of vector_ but allowed for it to be mutated?" No, `const` here applies to the contents of the vector. The vector isn't a pointer, but what you're talking about could be done with pointers, by making the pointer itself `const` instead of the contents of what it points to `const`. Also, `const` and `mutable` are opposites. One undoes the other. You cannot have both in effect at the same time. By definition something constant is immutable (unchangeable), and something mutable is non-constant.

Comment: @Carpetfizz, I massively expanded my answer to show how to do what you were thinking. Take a look.

Comment: Also keep in mind: don't create pointers or smart pointers unnecessarily. If you can create something statically, that's always the way to go, even when using pointers (just use statically-allocated pointers to statically-allocated data). Your private vector object, `vec_`, is created statically at compile-time, which is good. It will then automatically use dynamic memory allocation under-the-hood during run-time, as necessary, as it fills up when appending to it. Use explicit dynamic memory allocation, including smart pointers, only where necessary. ...

Comment: ...  Smart pointers are a means of better managing dynamic memory allocation, to *avoid* accidentally creating memory leaks by forgetting to properly use the `delete` keyword, and should only be used when dynamic memory allocation is required. Again, prefer static memory allocation, including for variables/objects of C++ Standard Library container types (which may then rely on dynamic memory allocation under-the-hood as they are used and as they grow), wherever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Original answer:

Your `std::vector`, `vec_` is `const`. Seems to me that would forcefully remove or disable any method, such as `push_back()`, which tries to modify the const vector.

---

### Additions added 10 May 2020:

I think it's worth expounding upon this comment from @Carpetfizz in the comments under his question, too:

> @GabrielStaples thanks, removing `const` did the trick. I thought `const` only protected against reassignment of vector_ but allowed for it to be mutated?

My response:

> No, `const` here applies to the contents of the vector. The vector isn't a pointer, but what you're talking about could be done with pointers, by making the pointer itself `const` instead of the contents of what it points to `const`. Also, `const` and `mutable` are opposites. One undoes the other. You cannot have both in effect at the same time. By definition, something constant is immutable (unchangeable), and something mutable is non-constant.

**And how might one make a pointer const but not the contents of what it points to?**

First, consider the original code (with some minor modifications/fixes I did to it):

Run it yourself online here: https://onlinegdb.com/SyMqoeU9L

**1) cpp_template_const_vector_of_smart_ptrs_test_BEFORE.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
    // const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vec_; // does NOT work 
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vec_;          // works!


public:
    void append(std::shared_ptr<T> item)
    {
        vec_.push_back(std::move(item));
    }

    void printElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_.size(); i++) 
        { 
            // Don't forget to dereference the pointer with `*` in order to 
            // obtain the _contens of the pointer_ (ie: what it points to),
            // rather than the pointer (address) itself
            std::cout << *vec_[i] << std::endl; 
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::unique_ptr<Container<std::string>> c = std::make_unique<Container<std::string>>();

    c->append(std::make_shared<std::string>("hello"));
    c->append(std::make_shared<std::string>("world"));

    c->printElements();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

And here's the new code demonstrating how to make a constant pointer to a non-const vector. See my comments here, and study the changes:

Run it yourself online here: https://onlinegdb.com/HyjNx-L5U

**2) cpp_template_const_vector_of_smart_ptrs_test_AFTER.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Container
{
private:
    // const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vec_; // does NOT work 

    // Create an alias to this type just to make the creation below less 
    // redundant in typing out the long type 
    using vec_type = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>;

    // NON-const object (vector)--so it can be changed 
    vec_type vec_;
    // const pointer to NON-const object--so, vec_p_ can NOT be re-assigned to
    // point to a new vector, because it is `const`! But, **what it points to**
    // CAN be changed because it is NOT const!
    vec_type * const vec_p_ = &vec_;

    // This also does NOT work (in place of the line above) because it makes 
    // the **contents of what you're pointing to const**, which means again 
    // that the contents of the vector can NOT be modified. 
    // const vec_type * const vec_p_ = &vec_; // does NOT work 
    // Here's the compile-time error in gcc when compiling for C++17:
    //      main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Container<T>::append(std::shared_ptr<_Tp>) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
    //      <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',78)">main.cpp:78:53</span>:   required from here
    //      main.cpp:61:9: error: passing ‘const vec_type {aka const std::vector >, std::allocator > > >}’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    //               vec_p_->push_back(std::move(item));
    //               ^~~~~~
    //      In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:64:0,
    //                       from main.cpp:22:
    //      /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:953:7: note:   in call to ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr >; _Alloc = std::allocator > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::shared_ptr >]’
    //             push_back(value_type&& __x)
    //             ^~~~~~~~~


    // To prove that vec_p_ can NOT be re-assigned to point to a new vector, 
    // watch this:
    vec_type vec2_;
    // vec_p_ = &vec2_; // COMPILE-TIME ERROR! Here is the error:
    //      main.cpp:44:5: error: ‘vec_p_’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘vec_type’?
    //           vec_p_ = &vec2_; // COMPILE-TIME ERROR!
    //           ^~~~~~
    //           vec_type

    // BUT, this works just fine:
    vec_type * vec_p2_ = &vec2_; // non-const pointer to non-const data 

public:
    void append(std::shared_ptr<T> item)
    {
        vec_p_->push_back(std::move(item));
    }

    void printElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_p_->size(); i++) 
        { 
            // Notice we have to use a double de-reference here now!
            std::cout << *(*vec_p_)[i] << std::endl; 
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::unique_ptr<Container<std::string>> c = std::make_unique<Container<std::string>>();

    c->append(std::make_shared<std::string>("hello"));
    c->append(std::make_shared<std::string>("world"));

    c->printElements();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra details!